Joblib Error After Upgrading From Python3.10 to python3.11
After updating from python3.10 to python3.11, a simple command like the following:
joblib.load("test.pkl")

Fails with error
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'sys.version_info'
Full error:
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 658, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 577, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/pickle.py", line 1213, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/pickle.py", line 1538, in load_stack_global
    self.append(self.find_class(module, name))
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/pickle.py", line 1580, in find_class
    __import__(module, level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/category_encoders/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from category_encoders.backward_difference import BackwardDifferenceEncoder
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/category_encoders/backward_difference.py", line 4, in <module>
    from patsy.contrasts import Diff
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/patsy/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    import patsy.highlevel
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/patsy/highlevel.py", line 19, in <module>
    from patsy.design_info import DesignMatrix, DesignInfo
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/patsy/design_info.py", line 38, in <module>
    from patsy.desc import ModelDesc, Term
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/patsy/desc.py", line 14, in <module>
    from patsy.eval import EvalEnvironment, EvalFactor
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/patsy/eval.py", line 36, in <module>
    _ALL_FUTURE_FLAGS = _all_future_flags()
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/patsy/eval.py", line 32, in _all_future_flags
    if feature.getMandatoryRelease() > sys.version_info:

Attempted to update joblib to most recent version (1.4.0) but this did not fix the issue. (This is on Ubuntu if that is relevant in any regard)

You have to update pasty itself. Older versions of pasty are not compatible with python 3.11.
